# Hp envy x360 internal speakers not working

Tags: debian, audio

I realize this issue has been posted already. Is there no progress? Is anyone working on it? I was so impressed with Debian 12 installation - even the wifi was recognized and working! But no sound. :-( I can use headphones or cast browser tabs to a tv. But nothing from the B&O speakers. I'll post some info if anyone wants to look into it but I really just wanted a status update on the issue. TIA!

```
# uname -a
Linux [host name] 6.4.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.4.4-2 (2023-07-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# lshw
[host name]
    description: Convertible
    product: HP Envy x360 2-in-1 Laptop 15-fh0xxx (n/a)
    vendor: HP
    version: Type1ProductConfigId
    serial: n/a
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.3.0 dmi-3.3.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=convertible family=103C_5335M8 HP Envy sku=n/a uuid=c9157e85-afd9-ed11-8c91-7c4d8fb88d44
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 8BE9
       vendor: HP
       physical id: 0
       version: 75.29
       serial: n/a
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Insyde
          physical id: 0
          version: F.03
          date: 04/06/2023
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 16MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD Ryzen 7 7730U with Radeon Graphics
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 25.80.0
          serial: Unknown
          slot: FP6
          size: 1600MHz
          capacity: 4546MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf rapl pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr rdpru wbnoinvd cppc arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif v_spec_ctrl umip pku ospke vaes vpclmulqdq rdpid overflow_recov succor smca fsrm cpufreq
          configuration: cores=8 enabledcores=8 microcode=173015053 threads=16
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1 - Cache
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 512KiB
             clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2 - Cache
             size: 4MiB
             capacity: 4MiB
             clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L3 - Cache
             size: 16MiB
             capacity: 16MiB
             clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 25
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: LPDDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 4266 MHz (0.2 ns)
             product: K4UBE3D4AB-MGCL
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             serial: Not Available
             slot: Bottom - on board
             size: 8GiB
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 4266MHz (0.2ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: LPDDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 4266 MHz (0.2 ns)
             product: K4UBE3D4AB-MGCL
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 1
             serial: Not Available
             slot: Bottom - on board
             size: 8GiB
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 4266MHz (0.2ns)
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-generic UNCLAIMED
             description: IOMMU
             product: Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 0.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:00.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi ht bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 1.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:36 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:d0800000-d08fffff ioport:450600000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: wlo1
                version: 01
                serial: 40:1a:58:15:49:48
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852ce driverversion=6.4.0-1-amd64 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:99 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0800000-d08fffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:37 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:d0700000-d07fffff ioport:450200000(size=2097152)
           *-generic
                description: MMC Host
                product: RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: mmc0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:45 memory:d0700000-d0700fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:38 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:d0600000-d06fffff ioport:450400000(size=2097152)
           *-nvme
                description: NVMe device
                product: KBG50ZNV512G KIOXIA
                vendor: KIOXIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: /dev/nvme0
                version: HP01AN00
                serial: n/a
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: nvme pm msi msix pciexpress nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0 nqn=nqn.2019-10.com.kioxia:KBG50ZNV512G KIOXIA:13APG1OQQMLK state=live
                resources: irq:63 memory:d0600000-d0603fff
              *-namespace:0
                   description: NVMe disk
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: hwmon3
              *-namespace:1
                   description: NVMe disk
                   physical id: 2
                   logical name: /dev/ng0n1
              *-namespace:2
                   description: NVMe disk
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: nvme@0:1
                   logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
                   size: 476GiB (512GB)
                   capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                   configuration: guid=8b9e5f14-082a-4960-a385-4aab0e45fa88 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 wwid=eui.00000000000000008ce38e040429b369
                 *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                      description: Windows FAT volume
                      vendor: mkfs.fat
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: nvme@0:1,1
                      version: FAT32
                      serial: n/a
                      size: 510MiB
                      capacity: 511MiB
                      capabilities: boot fat initialized
                      configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
                 *-volume:1
                      description: EXT4 volume
                      vendor: Linux
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: nvme@0:1,2
                      logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p2
                      logical name: /
                      version: 1.0
                      serial: n/a
                      size: 27GiB
                      capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                      configuration: created=2023-08-01 11:02:06 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2023-08-07 15:17:14 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2023-08-07 15:17:14 state=mounted
                 *-volume:2
                      description: Linux swap volume
                      vendor: Linux
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: nvme@0:1,3
                      logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p3
                      version: 1
                      serial: n/a
                      size: 976MiB
                      capacity: 976MiB
                      capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                      configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
                 *-volume:3
                      description: EXT4 volume
                      vendor: Linux
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: nvme@0:1,4
                      logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p4
                      logical name: /home
                      version: 1.0
                      serial: n/a
                      size: 447GiB
                      capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                      configuration: created=2023-08-01 11:02:06 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/home modified=2023-08-07 15:17:14 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2023-08-07 15:17:14 state=mounted
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 8.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:39 ioport:1000(size=4096) memory:d0100000-d05fffff ioport:fce0000000(size=270532608)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Barcelo
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: /dev/fb0
                version: c4
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
                configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
                resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:54 memory:fce0000000-fcefffffff memory:fcf0000000-fcf01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d0500000-d057ffff
           *-multimedia:0
                description: Audio device
                product: Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
                logical name: card1
                logical name: /dev/snd/controlC1
                logical name: /dev/snd/hwC1D0
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D3p
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D7p
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D8p
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:97 memory:d05c8000-d05cbfff
              *-input:0
                   product: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: input20
                   logical name: /dev/input/event16
              *-input:1
                   product: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=7
                   physical id: 1
                   logical name: input21
                   logical name: /dev/input/event5
              *-input:2
                   product: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=8
                   physical id: 2
                   logical name: input22
                   logical name: /dev/input/event6
           *-generic:0
                description: Encryption controller
                product: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.2
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=ccp latency=0
                resources: irq:43 memory:d0400000-d04fffff memory:d05ce000-d05cffff
           *-usb:0
                description: USB controller
                product: Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.3
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.3
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:44 memory:d0100000-d01fffff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 6.4.0-1-amd64 xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@1
                   logical name: usb1
                   version: 6.04
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                      product: Bluetooth Radio
                      vendor: Realtek
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: usb@1:3
                      version: 0.00
                      serial: 00e04c000001
                      capabilities: bluetooth usb-1.00
                      configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Video
                      product: HP Wide Vision 5MP Camera
                      vendor: Quanta
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@1:4
                      version: 0.05
                      serial: 0001
                      capabilities: usb-2.01
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 6.4.0-1-amd64 xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2
                   logical name: usb2
                   version: 6.04
                   capabilities: usb-3.10
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=10000Mbit/s
           *-usb:1
                description: USB controller
                product: Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.4
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.4
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:54 memory:d0200000-d02fffff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 6.4.0-1-amd64 xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@3
                   logical name: usb3
                   version: 6.04
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 6.4.0-1-amd64 xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@4
                   logical name: usb4
                   version: 6.04
                   capabilities: usb-3.10
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=10000Mbit/s
           *-multimedia:1
                description: Multimedia controller
                product: ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.5
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.5
                logical name: card2
                logical name: /dev/snd/controlC2
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D0c
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_rn_pci_acp3x latency=0
                resources: irq:92 memory:d0580000-d05bffff
           *-multimedia:2
                description: Audio device
                product: Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.6
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.6
                logical name: card0
                logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
                logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:98 memory:d05c0000-d05c7fff
              *-input:0
                   product: HD-Audio Generic Mic
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: input23
                   logical name: /dev/input/event17
              *-input:1
                   product: HD-Audio Generic Headphone
                   physical id: 1
                   logical name: input24
                   logical name: /dev/input/event7
           *-generic:1
                description: Signal processing controller
                product: Sensor Fusion Hub
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.7
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.7
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=pcie_mp2_amd latency=0
                resources: irq:44 memory:d0300000-d03fffff memory:d05cc000-d05cdfff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 8.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 memory:d0000000-d00fffff
           *-sata:0
                description: SATA controller
                product: FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                version: 81
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: sata pm pciexpress msi ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
                resources: irq:82 memory:d0001000-d00017ff
           *-sata:1
                description: SATA controller
                product: FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
                version: 81
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: sata pm pciexpress msi ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
                resources: irq:84 memory:d0000000-d00007ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: FCH SMBus Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 51
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: FCH LPC Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 51
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
           *-pnp00:00
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 0
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:01
                product: PnP device HPQ8001
                physical id: 1
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
           *-pnp00:02
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 2
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:03
                product: PnP device PNP0c01
                physical id: 3
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 107
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:8
          description: Host bridge
          product: Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 108
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:9
          description: Host bridge
          product: Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 109
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:10
          description: Host bridge
          product: Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 10a
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.6
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:11
          description: Host bridge
          product: Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 10b
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.7
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
  *-battery
       product: SA04055
       vendor: 333-17-4B-A
       physical id: 1
       version: 0
       serial: 0
       slot: Primary
       capacity: 55665mWh
       configuration: voltage=15.0V
  *-input:0
       product: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
       physical id: 2
       logical name: input0
       logical name: /dev/input/event0
       logical name: input0::capslock
       logical name: input0::numlock
       logical name: input0::scrolllock
       capabilities: i8042
  *-input:1
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 3
       logical name: input1
       logical name: /dev/input/event1
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:2
       product: Video Bus
       physical id: 4
       logical name: input15
       logical name: /dev/input/event13
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:3
       product: PC Speaker
       physical id: 5
       logical name: input19
       logical name: /dev/input/event4
       capabilities: isa
  *-input:4
       product: Lid Switch
       physical id: 6
       logical name: input2
       logical name: /dev/input/event2
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:5
       [clipped for length]
```